# jQuery - Toggle a panel closed on click of outside element, only if panel is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, triggers

I'm working on this site: http://dev.rjlacount.com/treinaAronson/index.php

My final to-do is to set the contact panel (which you can see if you click the top left "contact" button) to close if it's currently open and the user either clicks outside of the panel (in the "#content" area) or hits the esc key.

I figured the clicking in the #content area trigger would be the easier of the two, so I started with that. I've read a couple threads on triggering functions only if elements are visible, but what I've come up with so far isn't working at all:

```
$("#panel").is(":visible") {
  $("#content").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("3000");
  });
};
```

This breaks the functionality of the contact button, and I've tried several variations of this to no avail. Am I making any glaring errors here? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind `Click` and `Keydown` functions to the document and make sure the `click` function doesn't bubble up to the document when your panel or flip buttons are clicked.  Like so:

```
$(document).bind({
    keydown:function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27 ) {
            $("#panel").slideUp("3000");
        }
    }, click: function(e) {
        $("#panel").slideUp("3000");
    }
});
$('#flip, #panel').bind('click', function(e){return false});
```

Comment: Amazing, this solved both of my problems and I learned some new stuff. Thank you SO much!

Comment: Hey Marlin, I sent this to the friend I'm coding this site for and he requested the esc key also close the modal window that pops up if you click the "Refer a friend" link next to the contact panel. The code handling the modal window closing starts on line 82 of http://dev.rjlacount.com/treinaAronson/js/javascript.js. I haven't been able to figure out how to integrate it into the code you wrote for the previous problem into this. Any chance I could get some help here? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: sure, just add $("#refer-friend").fadeOut("3000"); within the if statement of the keydown function above.  That should do the trick

Comment: Hey Marlin, I know this is totally late, the project got pushed out and I hadn't revisited until now. But I just wanted to say thank you again. This worked perfectly, and I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a class to the body of the page when the panel is opened and remove it when it's closed?  That makes this much simpler:

```
$('.class #content').click(function(){
// Close the contact panel
});
```

Now, when the body has a class of 'class', any click on the #content div will automatically close contact.

Make sense?  Great looking site, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the response; Marlin's reply solved both my problems this time, but this totally makes sense and I will probably use it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#flip').bind('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('contactOpen');
    $("#panel").slideToggle("3000");
});

$('#content').bind('click', function(){
    if($('#flip').hasClass('contactOpen')){
        $(this).toggleClass('contactOpen');
        $("#panel").slideToggle("3000");
    }
});
```